# Is it possible to run ssl offline?

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx

I have a web-app deployed on cloud with ssl (using freeencrypt with nginx)
 The app is dockerized.
Is it possible for me to run it on localhost just by copying it and run `docker-compose up`?

Comment: It depends on the app you dockerized, but probably not. SSL relies on domain names, and perhaps you don't have a local DNS server that will handle this. You will surely encounter loads of problems if you want to run it locally

Comment: @ArthurAttout -- You can certainly embed an IP address as a SubjectAltName in a certificate, and then access the system without DNS in use, no "loads of problems" involved. Similarly, it's not exactly hard to run a locally-customized resolver (telling dnsmasq to serve an /etc/hosts file's contents over DNS is pretty much trivial).

Comment: Sure, it remains completely doable, I never wanted to let understand it's impossible. But it'll definitely require some workaround, more than a simple `docker-compose up` with environment variables as localhost

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for me to run it on localhost just by copying it and run docker-compose up?

Sure, that's entirely possible.  There's nothing particularly different about running it locally vs running it remotely: in both cases, you're still interacting with your web app with a browser over a network connection.

The only tricky bit may be in ensuring that you can continue to use the appropriate hostname so that your SSL certificate will validate correctly. The easiest way to do this is probably to modify your `/etc/hosts` file to map the hostname to the ip address of your webapp container.  This will override DNS.  Just remove to remove the modification when you're done testing, otherwise you won't be able to reach the remote site!